# Swift Drag&Drop - Move multiple items at once within the same collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview

I'm currently trying to implement Drag&Drop in my app. I've watched this:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/223/

(There's also a downloadable project that exactly showcases what I'm about to ask)

There's one thing I don't understand and that's this:

[image]

When I drag one item, I can drop it within the same collection view. However, that's not working anymore when I drag multiple items. No "gap" is created and when I drop the items, they just go back to their old positions.

Does this have any specific reason I'm not seeing? Because I'd love to have this feature.

I mean, I probably could implement the actual "moving the data" part (it's just a case that the demo project is not considering), but I see no way of adding this "gap" while hovering over the items.

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not supported with the latest set of APIs (as of iOS 13). It's possible to do by returning a proposal with intent `.unspecified` and drawing a drop indicator manually.

See [tweet reply from Tyler Fox, Apple engineer](https://twitter.com/smileyborg/status/1235966118562377729).

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tried moving multiple items before, but the way you “create space” for a single item is by using `collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: IndexPath)` and it’s companion functions. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618019-begininteractivemovementforitem

Comment: Isn't this used by the "old" system for collectionViews? Before IOS 11 introduced `Drag&Drop`. I'm not sure this is compatible (I think Drag&Drop uses this privately. I don't know where you could call this method)

Comment: From my understanding Drag&Drop is more for moving content between Applications or Views.  I am using this in my application FXpress and it works fine on iOS 11.  You need to use a longPress gesture recognizer, and call the methods from it, UICollectionView provides a default implementation you can use by setting `collectionView.installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement = true`.  The bonus is this works on iPhone too.

Comment: Yes, but also for moving within the same view. That's the great part, as I understand it. The thing is, I need to be able to drag from an arbitrary view to a collectionView, vice versa, and also between different (and identical) collectionViews. I can't do that with the old system. (Also, you can enable Drag&Drop on iPhones, it's just disabled by default for collectionViews).

Comment: In that case, I would suspect that if multiple items are dropped they may be wrapped in an Array, and perhaps that needs to be checked in `collectionView(_:canHandle:)`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I checked the documentation and it says `If you do not implement this method, the collection view assumes a return value of true`. So by default, it should be working with multiple items

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope, I ended up building my own drag and drop system. That made everything much more flexible for my use cases